# SQL Case Statement not working with 'Else'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

The following Case statements do not work correctly - producing all results as 'i' (the 'Else' part of the statement).
If I comment out the *Else* parts the code works ok, producing NULLs where the criteria isn't met.
Any ideas why this is happening? Is ELSE not supported? I'm sure I've seen Else used in Case statements (but never with *And*)?

```
SELECT 
        EN,
        (First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name) as Name,

        First_Aid =MAX(CASE
            WHEN Course = 'First Aid' 
            and Status = 'Finished'
            and Course_Start_Date > DATEADD(day, -1095, GETDATE())
            THEN 'F'
            ELSE 'i'
            END),

        Manual_Handling =MAX(CASE
            WHEN Course = 'Manual Handling' 
            and Status = 'Finished'
            and Course_Start_Date > DATEADD(day, -1095, GETDATE())
            THEN 'F'
            ELSE 'i'
            END),

        Fire_Safety =MAX(CASE
            WHEN Course = 'Fire Safety' 
            and Status = 'Finished'
            and Course_Start_Date > DATEADD(day, -1095, GETDATE())
            THEN 'F'
            ELSE 'i'
            END)
into MyTraining
FROM Learning_History

Group By EN,First_Name, Last_Name
```

Comment: What you have is essentially `MAX('F', 'i')`. The result is `'i'` if at least one record does not match the criteria. In no case this `case` would give a `null` - why do you expect it?

Comment: And of course, the reason it "works" when you don't have the `else` is because `max('F', null)` returns `'F'`. It's not `else`'s fault, just a tiny lapse in logic :)

Comment: Thanks for such quick reponses. As a beginner I think I am over-reaching my abilities as it is taking me ages to phrase a question, then I don’t understand the answers – my bad. @Luann – your suggestion gives me the same results as my code with the Else commented out, except there are course dates where I get ‘F’s’. Maybe this link <http://i.stack.imgur.com/c8oJO.png> shows what I am trying to achieve better?

Answer (score 2):

As GSerg commented, you're asking for the wrong thing. You probably want to use a query like this instead:

```
Fire_Safety =MAX(CASE
WHEN Course = 'Fire Safety' 
and Status = 'Finished'
and Course_Start_Date > DATEADD(day, -1095, GETDATE())
THEN Course_Start_Date
ELSE null
END)
```

This will give you the nearest day of the fire safety course, or `null` if there's none that satisfy the condition. You can then have another `case` around the `max` if needed to return either `T` or `F` or whatever you want based on the value returned. Or not, it's not really clear what you want to happen in either case :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pull the assignment to I and F outside the aggregation.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT EN,
       (First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name) as Name,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Course = 'First Aid' and Status = 'Finished' and Course_Start_Date > DATEADD(day, -1095, GETDATE())
                           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
             THEN 'F' ELSE 'I'
        END) as First_Aid,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN course = 'Manual Handling' and Status = 'Finished' and Course_Start_Date > DATEADD(day, -1095, GETDATE()) > 0
                          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
             THEN 'F' ELSE 'I'
        END) as Manual_Handling,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Course = 'Fire Safety' and Status = 'Finished' and Course_Start_Date > DATEADD(day, -1095, GETDATE())
                               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
            THEN 'F'
            ELSE 'i'
        END) as Fire_Safety
into MyTraining
FROM Learning_History
Group By EN, First_Name, Last_Name
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I am getting Incorrect syntax near '>'.  I notice you have an extra > 0 on the middle case expression. I removed it but still errors.